# Can sour cream be made the same way as yogurt?

Tags: yogurt, fermentation, sour-cream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make Sour Cream at home?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/is-it-possible-to-make-sour-cream-at-home)

I make yogurt by adding a small amount of yogurt to milk, heating it slightly (*barely* in this weather!) and letting it sit several hours. It's, of course, a simple process--that's rather what yogurt is all about.

I understand sour cream is made by the same essential process, but I don't know what changes I would need to make. Could I just add a little yogurt to some cream? Do I need to change the ratio of fresh to culture? Does the incubation time or temperature change at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can make sour cream by adding live-culture buttermilk or yoghurt to regular cream. Use 2 tablespoons of culture per cup of cream, mix, and let it sit for 12 hours in a warm place before putting in the fridge.